# Number of ways to disperse 4 guests in 6 hotels

Tags: combinatorics

I got this question in a past test and was revising it with my students.

Four visitors arrive in a town with six hotels. In how many ways can they disperse themselves into the hotels? (2 marks)

I suggested $^6P_4=360$ ways. I backed this up by saying that the visitors are distinguishable and with 2 marks the rigor should not be too involving.

While I still believe the visitors are distinguishable, I think each of the hotels can accommodate more than all the four visitors. My dilemma is the Mathematics for all these permutations. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

If the guests are **distinguishable**, then each guest must stay in one of the hotels with no further restrictions.  There are
$$
6^4 = 1296
$$
possibilities.

If the guests are **indistinguishable** (so each hotel has *some number* of guests), then you can use the stars and bars argument to see that there are
$$
\binom{4 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{9}{5} = 126
$$
possibilities.